# Navigate between two Placeholders with a LinkButton in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an aspx contentpage wherein there are two placeholders.

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plh1" runat="server" Visible="false">
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plh2" runat="server">
```

plh1 is set to true on Page_Load() and the other false. I have got a LinkButton inside plh1.
On clicking the LinkButton the same aspx page is to be loaded with the controls of plh2. Please  let me know what to do as I am a newbie and require assistance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the click event of the link button:

```
plh1.Visible = true;
plh2.Visible = false;
```

Was there a problem you had doing that?

Comment: @user1080139 "It didn't work" doesn't really mean anything.  What didn't work?  Was there an error, if so, what was it?  What *did* happen?  What, exactly did you do?

Comment: @Servy.. It works now !!! Thanks a lot.. Sorry, as I am a newbie I did not quite know the way of explanation..

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do this in panels or divs.  Put the appropriate controls in each panel, and in the code behind for the link button, set each panel visible to true or false.

If the button is meant to toggle between the two panels, you could just do something like

```
Panel1.Visible = Panel2.Visible;
Panel2.Visible = !Panel2.Visible
```

A PlaceHolder is what you would use if you are dynamically adding controls.  I would only recommend that where the number or type of controls to be added will change based on the user, or user's actions.  If you have controls you want to hide until a user clicks a button and then show those controls, and hide some others, you do not need to dynamically *add* controls, just to dynamically *control the display* of those controls.  That is a job for panels, divs or some other container with static controls.

Comment: @KennyZ.. Thanks for the explanation. But the requirement is that I gotta use placeholders only.